# How to set UITableViewCell's background color using mutiple small images?

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I use UITableViewCell, I want set cell's background color using the one small image(size is 10*10). How can I implement this?

Just for example,  the UITableViewCell size is 320*20, I want set it's background color using 32*2 small images, just like tile the small images.

Comment: try with `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tail_png"]]`

Answer (score 0):

As i commented, u can use `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` method of `UIColor` 
for example

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tile.png"]]; //the size as of tile.png may hav (10 * 10)
```

hope this helps u .. :)